# Как поместить большой кусок html в js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json

Мне нужно динамически создавать (на основе `json`) компоненты слайдера (хранятся в `li`).
Вот код который нужно вставить в ul:

```
<li class="slider__li">
    <div class="slider__block">
        <div class="slider__sale slider__sale-pos">-30%</div>
        <div class="slider__img"><img src="/images/b1.png" alt=""></div>
    </div>
</li>
```

Вот код jquery который работает с json:

```
$.getJSON('js/sliders.json', function (data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.slider1.length; i++) {

        var k = "Вот сюда нужно вставить HTML";
        $('.slider__ul').append(k);
    };
});
```

Но когда я вставляю код `html` в переменную, там происходит конфликт с "кавычками", и в итоге получается не строка, а черти что, и вставить туда элементы из `json` вообще невозможно.
Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: А что мешает заключить html строку не в двойные кавычки а в одинарные, то есть `var k = 'HTML';`?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский все так же. Дело в том, что и переход на следующую строку тоже вызывает проблему, я имел ввиду может есть кардинально другой способ.

Comment: Правильно. переход на другую строку надо конкатинировать...

Comment: @АлексейШиманский а если у меня будет 200 строк, тут хорошо хоть 5.

Comment: Ну нормальные IDE сами автоматом делают конкатенацию, когда пишешь на новой строке в js........ А если этим влом заниматься, то есть шаблонизаторы..... Или самому можно написать некий шаблон, в котором будет написана строка, а потом функция replace заменит все что нужно в одной строке на то, что в шаблоне прописано.........

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [jQuery Templates](https://github.com/KanbanSolutions/jquery-tmpl) или подобным плагином.

Оберните ваш HTML элементом `<script>`, добавьте `id`.

```
<script id="template" type="text/jquery-tmpl">
    <li class="slider__li">
        <div class="slider__block">
            <div class="slider__sale slider__sale-pos">-30%</div>
            <div class="slider__img"><img src="/images/b1.png" alt=""></div>
        </div>
    </li>
</script>
```

В обработчике добавьте вызов шаблонизатора.

```
$.getJSON('js/sliders.json', function (data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.slider1.length; i++) {

        var k = $('#template').tmpl(data.slider1[i]);
        $('.slider__ul').append(k);
    };
});
```

Comment: Отличное решение, сразу несколько проблем покрыло, спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Можно воспользоваться стандартом ES-2015.
Нужно в начале кода добавить `'use strict';` и заменить "" на ``. Вариант хорош тем что не требует каких либо дополнительных библиотек.

```
let multiline = `Это
    многострочный
    текст`;
```

В вашем случае так:

```
'use strict'; // Обязательно в начале документа

$.getJSON('js/sliders.json', function (data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.slider1.length; i++) {
        var k = `
          <li class="slider__li">
            <div class="slider__block">
              <div class="slider__sale slider__sale-pos">-30%</div>
              <div class="slider__img"><img src="/images/b1.png" alt=""></div>
            </div>
          </li>`;
        $('.slider__ul').append(k);
    };
});
```

Более подробно ([Строки в ES-2015](http://learn.javascript.ru/es-string))

Comment: Спасибо за совет, но к сожалению у меня не сработал такой вариант.

Comment: Какой браузер используете?

Answer (score 2):

По сути, надо в любом редакторе в начало `html` строк вставить `'`, а в конец `' +` :

```
$.getJSON('js/sliders.json', function (data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.slider1.length; i++) {

        var k = (
            ' <p> ' +
            '   <span>...</span> ' +
            ' </p> '
        );

        $('.slider__ul').append(k);
    };
});
```

Answer (score 2):

попробуйте вот такой решение с multiline кодом в JS
https://github.com/sindresorhus/multiline

```
Usage

Everything after the first newline and before the last will be returned   as seen below:

const str = multiline(function(){/*
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
    <h1>❤ unicorns</h1>
</body>
</html>
*/});
```

Comment: Что то я с ним не разобрался, сделал все как в инструкции. Какой js  файл нужно подключать? их там 5-6 штук и все названы не однозначно.

Comment: `<script src='browser.js'></script><script src='index.js'></script>`

Comment: ага, 2 файла, спасибо!